# Setting up Power BI to schedule publishing from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

My company suddenly switched to Power BI as a corporate visualization tool but I have a large PostgreSQL database/infrastructure in place.

I was able to download PostgreSQL drivers and connect to my data, but I am not seeing a way to schedule refreshes/publishing. If I go to the Power BI 'cloud' portal I see that the cloud can connect to Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, SQL Server Analysis Services, and Spark.

Can I configure the Power BI cloud to refresh data from my local PostgreSQL database? Or, if I create a Linux VM on Azure and install PostgreSQL, will I be able to schedule refreshes there? I just want to add the dashboards which update every 30 minutes so an end user just needs to refresh their browser. Or do I need to pipe data from PostgreSQL to a Microsoft DB?

I would much rather be able to use PostgreSQL if possible, and I would like to have Linux as well as the server OS because I am using Python Airflow to schedule tasks (don't think it works with Windows).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the [Power BI On-premises data gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-onprem/).  You'll need to install it on a Windows computer, along with the Postgres ODBC driver, but it shouldn't have any problem talking with your Postgres install on Linux.